# No Output...Not able to understand the error

Tags: java, arrays, frequency, word-frequency

This is my program for word count in a file containing a huge amount of data like about 3315 words. I do not want use a hash map .I have used hash map and got the output , but my task is to find another way of finding the frequency and the execution time difference between the two programs(i.e. the program with hash map and the program without one.)I have to use anything other than hashmap or sets.

Help please..

Thanks in advance.

```
package thirdassignments;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class WordFreq2 {

public void Working()
{

    FileInputStream in = null;
     try {
         in = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/kishansr/Desktop/file1.txt");
     } 
     catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         System.err.println("can’t open ");
         System.exit(1);
     }

     String word[]=new String[100000];
     int count[]={0},count1=0;
     Scanner input = new Scanner(in);

     //map<String,Integer> freq = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
     while (input.hasNext()) {
         count1=count1+1;
     }
     System.out.println(" Count: "+ count1);
     for(int i=0;i<=count1;i++)
     {
         String word1 = input.next().toLowerCase();
         System.out.println("word1 : " +word);
         if(word[i] != word1)
         {
             word[i]=word1;
             count[i]=1;
         }
         else if(word[i]==word1)
         {
             count[i]=count[i]+1;
         }

     }

      for (int i=0;i<count1;i++) {
         System.out.println(count[i] + " : " + word[i]);
     }


}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WordFreq2 wf = new WordFreq2();
    long startruntime = System.nanoTime();
    wf.Working();
    long endruntime = System.nanoTime();
     System.out.println("start time: "+startruntime+" ,end time :"+endruntime+" ,difference time: "+(endruntime - startruntime)+" nano seconds ");
}

}
```

Comment: you might forget to call `input.next()` inside `while (input.hasNext()) {}` that's why it's converted into an **infinite** loop. Always use both the methods in same loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex patter matching , Get first word , match word with remaining string and get count of it , print count and replace word it with blank and repeat process still all words get finished .